# Git to CVS migration steps

Tags: git, cvs

Can we migrate from git to cvs and keep meta data like author and time-stamp ?
i have tried 
https://github.com/klausi/git-cvs-export/blob/master/pull-cvs-export.sh

After testing it I lost author and time stamp 
No branches were exported

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to go from Git to ancient CVS?

Comment: Main reason is that later I will  convert from CVS to CC as i couldnt find a direct way to do it

Comment: CC as in ClearCase? Same question though, why go from Git to ancient ClearCase? ;P That being said, there seems to be [a bridge](https://github.com/charleso/git-cc) available but no idea how well it works. Overall, this seems like a rather bad idea though.